# Framework for pysiological time series in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have more and more work involving manipulation of physiological time series in `R`.
In most cases, we perform experiments with independent variables such as genotype and treatment:

`df <- expand.grid(treatment=c(T,F), genotype=LETTERS[1:5])
df
   treatment genotype
1       TRUE        A
2      FALSE        A
3       TRUE        B
4      FALSE        B
5       TRUE        C
6      FALSE        C
7       TRUE        D
8      FALSE        D
9       TRUE        E
10     FALSE        E`

In the past, I have mainly work with scalar response variables such as:

`df$Y <- rnorm(nrow(df))`

In this framework, `R` is formidable as it allows to plot, summarise or model data using very concise statements such as:

`aggregate(Y ~ treatment, df,mean)
  treatment          Y
1     FALSE  0.3832776
2      TRUE -0.4374324`

Now, instead of scalar values for `Y`, I am starting to record time series (multivariate) for each individual (e.g. physiological/behavioural data):

`df
   treatment genotype     Y
1       TRUE        A  TS_1
2      FALSE        A  TS_2
3       TRUE        B  TS_3
4      FALSE        B  TS_4
5       TRUE        C  TS_5
6      FALSE        C  TS_6
7       TRUE        D  TS_7
8      FALSE        D  TS_8
9       TRUE        E  TS_9
10     FALSE        E TS_10`

Where `TS_i` is a time series of variable (between individuals) length.
Most of my preliminary work is going to involve grouping time series per explanatory variable in order to summarise/describe/plot trends.

Ideally, I could define arbitrary functions (e.g. `averageNTimeSeries`) taking lists of time series as arguments and returning one time series (or even one scalar) and do things like:

`simple_df <- aggregate(Y ~ treatment, df, averageNTimeSeries)`

Although `aggregate` does not allow this, functions such as `dlply{plyr}` can be used to work around.
However, I presume other researchers have had similar issues and there might be a established framework (that I don't need to reinvent) to do exactly that.

My questions are:

1. `data.frame` objects can be forced to store `Y` as a list of lists instead of a vector, but this seems very "unnatural". Is there any other data container that could suit?
2. What sort of framework is used by other `R` users in such cases. In the past, I have use 'sparse' data.frames with headers such as ("treatment", "genotype", "individual", "time", "y"), but it seems quite wrong as well, and becomes quickly hard to manage.
3. What object/package is the most suited for storing/plotting "relative" time series (as I am only interested in time *since the beginning of the experiment*, not calendar time).

Comment: convert it from wide form to long form and then you can use aggregate.

Comment: I suggest you narrow down your question(s) to the essential coding problem and skip the foreplay.